# "Suspicious assignment in copy constructor" for byte[] - What is suspicious?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a copy constructor for class, but Android Studio code inspection throws a warning I don't understand:

> Suspicious assignment in copy constructor of
> 'java.util.Arrays.copyOf(other.value, other.value.length)' to field
> value

```
public class CpuVariable extends BaseIdentifier {
    private int memoryType;
    private byte[] value;

    public CpuVariable(@NonNull CpuVariable other) {
        super(other);
        this.memoryType = other.memoryType;
        if (other.value != null) {
            this.value = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(other.value, other.value.length);
        }
    }
}
```

Changing code to

```
this.value = other.value
```

would remove the warning, but this is not an option since I need to create a deep copy or a clone for the field.

Am I coding something wrong or is it safe to ignore or suppress the warning?

Comment: I'm not sure about the specifics of this inspection, but it seems an incorrect warning to me.

Comment: Do you still get the warning if you use `this.value = other.value.clone();` ?

Comment: One of the rare cases where "android-studio" is actually a relevant tag since this is neither a normal Java issue nor a android issue but actually an "issue" with the IDE and its generated warnings.

Comment: copyOf method can throw exception, can it be because of that ?

Comment: @khelwood yes, clone throws the warning, too.

Comment: Unless there is any more information available from the warning, it does not seem very helpful

Comment: @khelwood Full inspection description is
`Suspicious assignment in copy constructor of 'java.util.Arrays.copyOf(other.value, other.value.length)' to field value 
 Inspection info: Reports a warinng if not all fields are assigned correctly in a copy constructor.`

Comment: @gvmani surrounding with exception handler does not remove the warning.

Comment: I wonder what'd happen if you added `else this.value = null`

Comment: @PetrJaneček assignment throws `Suspicious assignment in copy constructor of 'null' to field value `

Comment: Does `this.value = (other.value == null) ? null : other.value.clone();` still cause the warning to be emitted? It's essentially the same as the if-else approach, but perhaps the single LOC would satisfy the inspection. If not, then I suggest you just suppress the warning, as it seems like a false positive to me.

Comment: @Slaw your suggestion throws warning, too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is clearly a false positive.  There is nothing actually wrong with your constructor.

I think that the code that produced this warning is based on [this code](https://github.com/jkovacs/CopyConstructorPlugin/blob/master/src/de/umass/idea/copyConstructor/inspection/IncompleteCopyConstructorInspection.java).  Note that this is not the real Android Studio code, but there are clues to suggest that Android Studio may have "borrowed" it via some path.

If you look at the `constructorAssignsAllFields` method (line 63), the intent of the code seems to be to look for code bugs where a copy constructor is copying the wrong fields; e.g. something like this:

```
MyClass(MyClass other) {
   this.x = other.x;
   this.y = other.x; // Ooops
}
```

But the method is not correctly dealing with the case where the copy constructor is transforming one of the fields.

Looking at the code, you need to write `this.value =`  in a way that makes the checker not realize that it is assigning to a field.  For example, if you used a setter method something like this:

```
public CpuVariable(@NonNull CpuVariable other) {
    super(other);
    this.memoryType = other.memoryType;
    this.value = other.value;  // Dummy
    if (other.value != null) {
        this.setValue(java.util.Arrays.copyOf(other.value, other.value.length));
    }
}
```

Comment: > It is clearly a false positive.  
I think, actually it is, and you provided a helpful explanation and a solution for outsmarting the checker, but that needs some additional code and makes code harder too understand. So I prefer supressing the warning.
Anyway, your answer reassures me for coding right.

Comment: I would suppress the warning if it was my code.

Answer (score -1):

It appears this can also happen if there's any other problem with the copy constructor, such as if the copy constructor is not copying all fields. I'm also seeing this same error in IntelliJ in that case.